# OKHTTP caching: How to rewrite the URL of the response used for caching?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

okhttp cache's key cannot be changed (without modifying the source code) and it is md5 of the URL ([source](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.7.5/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Cache.java#L175))

I am trying to write an interceptor which will rewrite the URL in the response. But after looking at the implementation, I realized that it's not possible since the HttpEngine intentionally takes the URL from the *original* request as seen [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.7.5/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpEngine.java#L640) and [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.7.5/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpEngine.java#L133).

Is there a way around this except forking the source?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to rewrite the request URL. Otherwise conditional GETs wouldn't work.

Comment: Do you mean rewrite the request URL before making the request [via an interceptor]? 
Yes, I am doing that except I am hitting cache via a different URL and hitting the Internet via another.

Comment: Rewrite the URL in an application interceptor, and rewrite it back in a network interceptor.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse. That's what I tried but it seems that the eventual caching operation will use the original request's URL and not the modified URL. [Source](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.7.5/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpEngine.java#L133)

Comment: @ashishb - how did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I think I ended up using a separate Cache implementation for this.